# Password reset not working in Django 1.6.1

Tags: python, django, django-authentication

I'm using Django 1.6.1 and password reset is giving me a real headache. The user enters their email and receives a 502, and I receive this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 114, in get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 99, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/auth/views.py", line 158, in password_reset
    form.save(**opts)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/auth/forms.py", line 256, in save
    email = loader.render_to_string(email_template_name, c)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 164, in render_to_string
    return t.render(Context(dictionary))

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py", line 140, in render
    return self._render(context)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py", line 134, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py", line 840, in render
    bit = self.render_node(node, context)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py", line 854, in render_node
    return node.render(context)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 447, in render
    six.reraise(*exc_info)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 433, in render
    url = reverse(view_name, args=args, kwargs=kwargs, current_app=context.current_app)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 509, in reverse
    return iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs))

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 429, in _reverse_with_prefix
    (lookup_view_s, args, kwargs, len(patterns), patterns))

NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'auth_password_reset_confirm' with arguments '('MQ', u'3op-83ceb0bee07385a12e2a')' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
```

The relevant parts of urls.py (I redefined them rather than importing the default conf because I wanted to change the urls):

```
url(r'^password/change/$',
    auth_views.password_change,
    name='auth_password_change'),
url(r'^password/change/done/$',
    auth_views.password_change_done,
    name='password_change_done'),
url(r'^password/reset/$',
    auth_views.password_reset,
    name='auth_password_reset'),
url(r'^password/reset/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/(?P<token>[0-9A-Za-z]{1,13}-[0-9A-Za-z]{1,20})/$',
    auth_views.password_reset_confirm,
    name='password_reset_confirm'),
url(r'^password/reset/complete/$',
    auth_views.password_reset_complete,
    name='auth_password_reset_complete'),
url(r'^password/reset/done/$',
    auth_views.password_reset_done,
    name='password_reset_done'),
```

Any help please? I have no idea how to go about fixing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'auth_password_reset_confirm'
```

You have:

```
url(r'^password/reset/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/(?P<token>[0-9A-Za-z]{1,13}-[0-9A-Za-z]{1,20})/$',
    auth_views.password_reset_confirm,
    name='password_reset_confirm'),
```

The name attribute of that url looks like it should be `auth_password_reset_confirm`

Answer (score 0):

There has been [some changes in the authentication url names](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.6/#django-contrib-auth-password-reset-uses-base-64-encoding-of-user-pk%20Change) in Django-1.6.